# Creating a walk-through using Virtools

Tags: 3d, virtual, environment, 3dsmax, walkthrough

I'm creating a virtual walk-through in a museum environment.

I have constructed the 3D virtual environment in 3Ds Max and I need to create the walking part in Virtools.

I have found some tutorials on YouTube that show how to do simple character movement, but it shows only using keyboard navigations to move around.

I want to know how to walk around using mouse and keyboard like first person shooting game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the documentation installed, import the "Free Camera" sample from the "Virtools Resources/3D Entities/Scripted Cameras".

This will create a free cam, which navigate as in a FPS, using the mouse and keyboard (keys 8, 2, 4 and 6 on the num pad).

For collisions to work, you need to put the colliding 3D object in a group (in the Level Manager, select your 3D objects, then Right Click > Place selected in new group, then rename the created group).

In the schematic, in the script named "FreeCam Script", double click on the Object Slider box, and in the Group Field, select the group you just created.